# How can I get Twitter videos to continue playing even after their tab has lost focus?

Tags: twitter, video

One feature that I really like on Facebook is that I can start a video playing and then do other things. I can switch to a different tab and I will continue to listen to the video's audio playing while I'm interacting with other websites entirely. This is nice because sometimes all I want to do is listen to the video while I work; I don't need to give the video my full attention.

With Twitter this seems impossible. Their video players will autoplay the videos as you scroll past them with the sound muted. I will then un-mute the sound, but as soon as I flip away to another tab or another window, the Twitter videos automatically mute themselves again.

Is there some way to prevent this behavior? How can I ensure a Twitter video keeps playing (with sound) even after I change the focus?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In twitter settings uncheck the 'Video Autoplay' option, it seems to auto mute/pause too.

Just click your avatar the go into 'Settings and Privacy. It's under the content section in the account tab.

Comment: To be clear this only works if you can login. If you browse as a guest (without logging in) you can't adjust this setting.

Comment: How to make it auto play and auto sound on?

Answer (score 5):

Open Twitter in a separate window. It will continue playing.